# How to use jQuery Plugin with Angular 4?

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to use a range slider in an angular project and I tried using one available module for angular 4.

It works fine during compilation but when I try to build it for deployment, it throws the below error.

[image]

I checked for the option of using jQuery plugin directly in the angular project and I'm only getting options for doing it in Angular 2.

Is there any way we can use jQuery plugins in Angular 4?

Please let me know.

Comment: Wrap it in a component: https://hackernoon.com/wrap-any-jquery-plugin-with-angular-2-component-case-study-8b00eacec998 There is no difference between ng2 and ng4 from this perspective.

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Yes you can use jquery with Angular 4

Steps:

1) In `index.html` put below line in  tag.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2) In component ts file below you have to declare var like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular 4 with jquery';
  toggleTitle(){
    $('.title').slideToggle(); //
  }

}
```

And use this code for corresponding html file like this:

```
<h1 class="title" style="display:none">
  {{title}}
</h1>
<button (click)="toggleTitle()"> clickhere</button>
```

This will work for you. Thanks

Comment: It worked!! How would you use extended plugins like jquery-ui?

Comment: solved: npm install jquery && typings install dt~jquery --global --save

Comment: @Johannes Refer to typescript docs for typings http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html , http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Comment: @Jota.Toledo how would you suppose it should be done? Do you have any additional info about the right way to do it?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you mean add it to angular-cli.json? It seems really practical :) thanks for the advice

Comment: ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Comment: I think you lose code completion by declaring it as `any`. Try declaring it as `JQueryStatic` or `JQueryStatic<Element, HTMLElement>` to get code completion for jquery

Answer (score 190):

Install jquery with npm

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Add typings

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Add scripts to angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [{
  ...
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  ],
  ...
}]
```

Build project and serve

```
ng build
```

Comment: Also do not forget to `add declare var jquery:any;  
declare var $ :any;` to your .ts file.

Comment: @Norx the instructions include installing the types which means your lines are not needed.

Comment: I'm getting build errors when I do this. I have jquery 3.2.1 installed with the types, so it doesn't give me errors in the code, but I still get build errors stating: `Cannot find name '$'`

Comment: @Grungondola add `declare const $: any;` above the @... decorator.

Comment: Does this play well with Angular's zone.js ?

Comment: Just curious, why is this going into the angular-cli.json but not into the package.json?

Comment: @Ervin Llojku jquery click is not working in angular2 i hope you help me

Comment: 1. Try your jquery code in the console, just to see if the selector is ok and returns data. write the selector here pls

Comment: This only makes jQuery available not including the plugin itself. Say, you use bootstrap-select plugin, jQuery().selectpicker will not be recognized and there will be compilation error.

Comment: this should be the right answer but don't forget to add `bootstrap.js` to your `.angular-cli.json` file after `jquery.js`
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

Comment: When trying this, I get: "Unexpected token exports" in the browser console

Comment: EDIT: The issue i described is coming from trying to import Popper.js the exact same way right below jQuery.

Comment: this doesnt work if i just do ng serve. I tried adding to script section in angular.json. No luck,
However, adding the same line in index.html works like a charm for ng serve command.

Comment: @Zenwalker i guess you are doing something wrong. just check if you have the correct path to jquery.js

Comment: I think we still need to add import statement in the component file to get jquery working: **import * as $ from 'jquery';**

Answer (score 35):

Install jQuery using NPM
[Jquery NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery)

```
npm install jquery
```

Install the jQuery declaration file

```
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

Import jQuery inside .ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

call inside class

```
export class JqueryComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
    $(window).click(function () {
        alert('ok');
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 27):

You are not required to declare any jQuery variable as you installed @types/jquery.

```
declare var jquery:any;   // not required
declare var $ :any;   // not required
```

You should have access to jQuery everywhere.

The following should work:

```
jQuery('.title').slideToggle();
```

Comment: I get this error `Cannot find name 'jQuery'` if I'm not declaring them in the `.ts` file. So, if anyone faces this problem, he just needs to declare them.

Comment: I've had issues in the past where the mentioned import statements WERE required to get the TS compiler not to complain. However, I recently updated my packages and now those import statements cause my 3rd party plugins to not be defined. Here is my current configuration:
Angular version: 4.4.7
@angular/cli@1.7.4
jquery@3.3.1
typescript@2.3.4

Answer (score 13):

You should not use jQuery in Angular. While it is possible (see other answers for this question), it is discouraged. Why?

Angular holds an own representation of the DOM in its memory and doesn't use query-selectors (functions like `document.getElementById(id)`) like jQuery. Instead all the DOM-manipulation is done by Renderer2 (and Angular-directives like *ngFor and *ngIf accessing that Renderer2 in the background/framework-code). If you manipulate DOM with jQuery yourself you will sooner or later...

1. Run into synchronization problems and have things wrongly appearing or not disappearing at the right time from your screen
2. Have performance issues in more complex components, as Angular's internal DOM-representation is bound to zone.js and its change detection-mechanism - so updating the DOM manually will always block the thread your app is running on.
3. Have other confusing errors you don't know the origin of.
4. Not being able to test the application correctly (Jasmine requires you to know when elements have been rendered)
5. Not being able to use Angular Universal or WebWorkers

If you really want to include jQuery (for duck-taping some prototype that you will 100% definitively throw away), I recommend to at least include it in your package.json with `npm install --save jquery` instead of getting it from google's CDN.

> TLDR: For learning how to manipulate the DOM in the Angular way please go through the official tour-of heroes tutorial first: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 If you need to access elements higher up in the DOM hierarchy (parent or `document body`) or for some other reason directives like `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, custom directives, pipes and other angular utilities like `[style.background]`, `[class.myOwnCustomClass]`  don't satisfy your needs, use Renderer2: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-4-renderer2-example

Comment: I understand you point. But how to access DOM and change it in angular.  For eg  $('.js-eachoption[data-id=' + parentId + ']').closest('.eachLevel').after(html); How to do this with just angular.

Comment: @Pradeep in Angular you usually don't start looking for elements inside the DOM from the root html-tag, although that is also possible (by referencing DOCUMENT or WINDOW inside any component). Modularization (which Angular is made for) forces you to build your app in a way that you manipulate only child elements from parent elements. In a long term such a hierarchical dependency makes development and maintenance of code much easier. So you should try to manipulate only the host DOM-element of the current component or any ViewChild or ContentChild and their children.

Comment: @Pradeep So when you get a reference to an element (`constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}`), you can either filter for its children or manipulate the element directly by accessing it's nativeElement-Property: `ngOnInit() { this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'wild'); }`. Here is a tutorial how to tell you more: https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Comment: @Pradeep please keep in mind that renderer2 is not your only option. In Angular you can manipulate the DOM from the template directly. For example, DOM elements inside the current component's template can easily be handled with `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, custom (made by you) directives, pipes and for CSS `ngClass`, `[style.background]` and `[class.myCustomCssClass]`. For further help: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
```

Or add scripts to angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  ]
```

and in your .ts file:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your jquery typings version like so

```
npm install --save @types/jquery@latest
```

I had this same error and I've been at if for 5 days surfing the net for a solution.it worked for me and it should work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you have the need to use other libraries in projects --typescript-- not just in projects - angle - you can look for tds's (TypeScript Declaration File) that are depares and that have information of methods, types, functions, etc. , which can be used by TypeScript, usually without the need for import. declare var is the last resource

```
npm install @types/lib-name --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack to **provide** it. It will be then injected DOM automatically.

```
module.exports = {
  context: process.cwd(),
  entry: {
    something: [
      path.join(root, 'src/something.ts')
    ],
    vendor: ['jquery']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(root, '/dist/js'),
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map",
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.es6', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),

  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution to the typescript:

**Step1:**

```
npm install jquery

npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

**step2:** in Angular.json add:

```
"scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      ]
```

or in index.html add:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**step3:** in *.component.ts where you want to use jquery

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';  // dont need "declare let $"
```

Then you can use jquery the same as javaScript. This way, VScode supports auto-suggestion by Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Try using - 
declare let $ :any;

or import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
provide exact path of the lib

Answer (score -3):

```
ngOnInit() {
     const $ = window["$"];
     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        start: function (slider) {
          $('body').removeClass('loading')
        }
     })
}
```