# import jquery in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, javascript-import

in order to import jquery in an angualr4 project i do the following:

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

in the app.component.ts

```
import $ from 'jquery';
or 
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

when run "ng serve"
i got these errors

```
ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (47,40): ',' expected.

ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (2370,40): ',' expected.
.....
.....
.....
ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (4311,85): ';' expected.

ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (4311,92): Expression expected.

ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (4455,1): Declaration or statement expected.

ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (30,45): Generic type 'JQueryStatic<TElement, HTMLElement>' requires 2 type argument(s).
.....
.....
.....
ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (4475,33): Generic type 'PlainObject<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/src/app/app.component.ts (2,8): Module ''jquery'' has no default export.

ERROR in C:/jquery-angular/jqueryintegration/src/app/app.component.ts (2,8): Module ''jquery'' has no default export.
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

my enviroment details:

```
>tsc --version
Version 2.3.2

>ng --version
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
```

other dependecies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.3",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Does "import" load javascript file of default or must it be configured in some way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

`import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';`

Answer (score 6):

Install jquery package using npm following is the code to install jquery

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Add types

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Add scripts to angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [{
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", // check your ref path it might be different.
  ],
}]
```

In component, you need to add

```
declare var jquery:any;
```

Comment: The whole point of the @types libraries is so you don't have to `declare var jquery: any;`. The tip about "scripts" is good, but I think there's still something missing here.