# Angular 5 + SignalR (DefinitelyTyped) - Cannot find name '$'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, signalr

I'm trying to use **SignalR** in my **Angular 5** application.

I installed these strong typed from **DefinitelyTyped**:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
npm install --save @types/signalr
```

Typescript in my `packages.json` shows version **2.5.3**.

Now I'm trying to use it like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SignalRService {

    constructor() {}

    public ConnectTo(url: string): void {

        var hubConnection = $.hubConnection();
        var hubProxy = hubConnection.createHubProxy('DashboardHub');
        hubProxy.on('Example', (e: any) => {
            console.log('worked');
        });

        hubConnection.start();
    }
}
```

The compiler complains with the following:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
```

...even though intellisense can find `$.hub`:

[image: Image showing intellisense]

---

If I try adding `declare var $ :any;` to my file, it compiles but I get another error in browser's console: `$.hubConnection is not a function`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't declare $ yet : [reference to another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4)

Comment: @JanSomersJanS91 I thought this was an older way of doing this, whereas DefinitelyTypes would make this not to be required anymore. Anyway, if I add that, I get `$.hubConnection is not a function`.

Comment: Hmm strange that that isn't working ... maybe you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46113678/7018180)

Comment: @JanSomersJanS91 I tried `npm install jquery --save` and adding it to `angular-cli.json`, still `$.hubConnection is not a function`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use SignalR in Angular you need to do these steps:

Install jquery, signalr packages using npm:

```
npm install signalr
npm install jquery
```

Add types:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery 
npm install --save @types/signalr
```

Add scripts to angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [{
    "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
    ],
}]
```

And in service you need to add:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Simple Angular code example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;
@Injectable()
export class SignalrService {
    private connection: any;
    private proxy: any;
    private ulr: any;

    constructor() {}

    public startConnection(): void {
        this.connection = $.hubConnection(this.url);
        this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('ProcessingHub');

        this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
            console.log('Connected to Processing Hub');
            this.sendMessage();
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            console.log('Hub error -> ' + error);
        });
    }

    public sendMessage(): void {
        this.proxy.invoke('SendMessage', 'test')
           .catch((error: any) => {
               console.log('SendMessage error -> ' + error); 
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks I just forgot to change the `angular-cli.json`. I didn't even have to install the types, just installing jquery and signalr was enough.