# npm install --save jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04
I have proxy setup on ~/.npmrc, which looks like the following config

```
registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
proxy="http://username:password@proxyconfig:port"
strict-ssl=false
http-proxy="http://username:password@proxyconfig:port"
http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyconfig:port"
https_proxy="http://username:password@proxyconfig:port"
https-proxy="http://username:password@proxyconfig:port"
```

I keep on getting the following exception, everytime I try to download any dependency.

[image: exception]

Full Error log

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with sudo npm install --save jQuery ?

Comment: This is an angular 4 project

Comment: I have tried that, besides, this error appears on every dependency I'm trying to install

Comment: import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'; For  more details please Visit :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717488/import-jquery-in-angular4

Comment: Well, I'm not sure `0.75.70.145` is a valid ip address for your proxy.

Comment: 99% your proxy is blocking your or its not setup correctly.

Comment: Beside, I'm not sure this belongs to StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you post some lines from the debug.log? Otherwise this is just guessing.

Comment: @stamos thanks, I'll have a direct my attention to setting a proxy properly. proxy configuration is above, you reckon that's incorrect?

Comment: @PeterBranforn I've edited the post to include the full log regarding the issue. thanks in advance. I appreciate it

Comment: Sorry I am not a proxy expert but I hope you have changed `http://username:password@proxyconfig:port` to something like `http://stamos:Ow3s0m3P4$$W0rD#2018@82.93.104.105:3128` right?

Comment: @user2875912 thanks for the extra log output, but it does not contain extra hints... the extra call stack is nice, but beauty is rated rather low in an analysis context :D.

Comment: @Stamos yes, username, password and proxy is just a placeholder, without exposing my real credentials

Answer (score 2):

This error means that cannot open http://registry.npmjs.org/jquery url.

For checking this, you can paste this http://registry.npmjs.org/jquery url into browser to see whether succeed to request data.

If so, possilbly your network or DNS has problem.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: I've pasted it, on the browser, theres response. I will focus more on my proxy

Comment: Well, if the browser works, then its related to the proxy settings and the proxy actually functions. Is the proxy requiring an authentication? I found that sometimes passwords can contain special characters that break the proxy settings string in the config file.....

Comment: @PeterBranforn possibly, actually that might be the issue. I will try to change my password

Comment: @PeterBranforn that was the problem my password had charecters that breaks the proxy. thanks a million. I wouldn't have thought of it. thanks

Comment: I make this an answer-- :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the browser works, then its related to the proxy settings and the proxy actually functions. Is the proxy requiring an authentication? I found that sometimes passwords can contain special characters that break the proxy settings string in the config file.....

Comment: I just copied my comment over here after it was confirmed to be the solution, I hope nobody punishes me for this :-).

Answer (score 1):

Bound to be proxy issues.

set proxy settings:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

check proxy settings:

```
npm config --global list

npm config list
```

if you have a bunch of people who need the same proxy settings then you can set the proxy config in an .npmrc file

Here's the output of `npm config --global list` for me (I'm behind a proxy):

```
; cli configs
global = true
user-agent = "npm/3.10.10 node/v6.12.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig D:\Users\DDLewis\.npmrc
http-proxy = "http://MYPROXYIPADDRESS:MYPROXYPORT"
https-proxy = "http://MYPROXYIPADDRESS:MYPROXYPORT/"
proxy = "http://MYPROXYIPADDRESS:MYPROXYPORT/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "D:\\Users\\DDLewis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
```

Also see https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Comment: it was my password that broke the proxy