# Cannot serve Angular 5 project - Cannot find name '$'

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I just pulled a project, and did npm install. It works just fine at my work PC, but now I cannot start it, it keeps throwing error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
```

for multiple components. I installed latest node version and latest npm version, installed node modules and this happens, anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here, you must be using jquery in your project. As you mentioned you pulled and npm install, jquery must be installed with it. But you can try applying `npm install --save @types/jquery` and use `import * as $ from "jquery";` in all the components where you used or imported '$'(jquery).

You can get further info about using jquery in angular project from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717488/import-jquery-in-angular4)