# Different way to mix jQuery and Angular4

Tags: jquery, angular

I recently started learning Angular 4 in hopes to pick it up on a few projects (I am still learning a lot of the basics, so my question may seem obvious). In the past I have been using jQuery for most of my DOM manipulation, however now with using Angular, there are very obvious changes which make using jQuery within an Angular application a little more troublesome.

I have read over many Stack Overflow posts regarding using jQuery within an Angular project, however all of them suggest to write your jQuery functions from within the component typescript files. This makes sense since Angular is supposed to be based on components. My only question/concern is how about would you create global level jQuery functions outside of the component themselves.

For example, in the past I have always just created a js file to hold my jQuery functions and have them referenced within my html file. An example of this would be a parallax function for images. If I wanted to add a little different styling to different parallax images I could do this fine and still have my jQuery do its job, but now say for example I have two different parallax components that use the same jQuery code, is there a (right) way to reference the same function from within different components via a global js file that holds the jQuery code?

My assumption would be I could just create a file "xxxx.js" that holds the functions and have it referenced in the index.html file. I just want to know if something like what I have described is possible, and if so what is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would possibly be using dependency injection , 
 The approach would be :

1. Create a services file which holds all the common functionality
   across the functions.
2. Use them as providers in my target components.
3. Using Dependancy injection create object for such services and use them in my component.

As far as approach with " **Create a js and include in index.html and use across component**" , 
***yes it is possible*** .
 I have used it for 1 of the external library in my project which was a js file. Steps should be :

1. Copy the js file in src/assets/javascript
2. Add them in index.html

   ```
   <script src="assets/javascript/yourFile.js"></script>
   ```
3. declare your js function as shown in component section ( before component directive) as shown :

   ```
   declare var yourFunction: any;
   ```
4. Now you can use your function in the target component.

Comment: Ah so that solves half the problem. But now say as an example I have a a function that is fired on a specific event such as a window resize. Most of my functions arent named as they simply fire inline with the event. So something like $(window).on("resize", function(){ .... }); Would the approach you offered still work with something like this? Since there isnt a specific function to declare in the component  due to it firing on the window resize. In the case of my Parallax example, it fires on window scroll.

Comment: I am not very sure about it , but you can give it a try and see if it works , dont declare anything in component , just do step-1 & 2 and see if the event triggers your function.
Although i would suggest to use named functions , that makes code more readable , maintainable and fits in principles of typescript

Comment: Ya thats what Ill try, I mean.... if the js file with the jQuery is being added to the HTML file that Angular is building I would assume that the jQuery in its own file would still be able to operate as if it was just a standard HTML file.

Comment: yes , please try and please mark this as answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a framework as the angular, it starts to manipulate the elements and their events. Jquery does not work as you are accustomed because if you enter the scripts only once at the end of the page, the events will be applied to the current elements, but after the angular make any modification, the events will no longer be working.

Jquery is not recommended in conjunction with angular, however, if you want to take advantage of some features you have not yet found in a particular angled plugin, you can create an angular component that makes that binding, so you'll have to make the jquery call by applying to Elements you want, and obviously the ideal is you also take care of performing the unbind for some types of event.

Here's an example: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4)