# Implementing custom search in datatables.net with angular 4

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I'm trying to implement a simple custom search on a column.
This is well documented at https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html.
However my (so far) only problem is accessing the $.fn.dataTable.ext.search array, to add and later remove my custom search function.

What is the path for this array, when going through angular-datatables?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {

      dtInstance. <-- what goes here?
 });
```

Comment: `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` is a "global" list not specific to tables or dataTable instances. You should be able to use it right away (ad4 use $ internally). Perhaps you have [forgotten to declare the $ alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4) but `jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()` etc should work anywhere.

Comment: It claims that dataTable doesn't exist. Then when I change that to DataTable, it claims that ext doesn't exist.

Comment: It is almost waste of reps.  Please show your code, and please elaborate more than "*what goes here?*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was solved by the developer at https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1111

It was because the typings were not complete, when using typescript in angular.
Correct reference is `$.fn['dataTable'].ext.search`

Comment: can you provide a full code example for this with angular?