# Angular4 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an application written in Angular which uses jquery.
Generally everything works fine, but I'm struggling with declaring

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

in every component where I want to use it.

Does exist any smarter way to does it globally? I mean declare $ globally for whole application?

My instaltion proccess was the same as the last comment in the above topic:
[How to use jQuery Plugin with Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4/44653848)

but unfortunatelly if I don't declare $ or jQuery variable I got an error:

```
Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
```

Comment: are you using angular cli?

Comment: yes I am using cli

Comment: there isn't a way to do this because it's inadvisable.  It breaks modularity so that you can save like 2 lines per component.  Plus, You shouldn't depend so heavily on jquery in an angular project anyway.

Comment: ok, but I need some extra features which provides jquery, for ex. modals

Answer (score 0):

try  to add this in your vendor.ts

```
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
window['jQuery'] = window['$'] = jquery;
```

and after import your vendor.ts inside your main.ts

```
import './vendor.ts'
```

Comment: I don't have this file.

Comment: create it in the same directory as index.html and main.ts and put these 2 lines in it

Comment: It caused thousands various errors, all in the same directory (node_modules/@types/jquery/)

and an example error:

node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (7305,43): ',' expected.

Comment: what is the version of typescript??

Comment: and your version of @types/jquery

Comment: you can drop back to 2.x typings :  "@types/jquery": "<2.2",

Answer (score 0):

add this to your angular-cli.json

```
 "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
```

Comment: Say you have a datepicker that uses Jquery then make datepicker.directive and use it.