# import jQuery to specific module/component of angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I want to use the theme https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/ for one of my angular4+ projects. The theme uses jQuery and jQuery-UI libraries for various effects and js operations.

As per my understanding, we should avoid using jQuery to the Angular project. So I am planning to use it just for a module responsible for the landing screen(i.e. landing screen module of angular). And I think, I should avoid it to refer to directly on angular-cli.json (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653848/2989541) which makes it available application wide. Can anyone please suggest the better way to the same?

Is something like  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43962339/2989541 is okay to go with?

Sorry, being new and due to lack of the reputation points, I am unable to make comment on the existing questions to clarify my issue, so creating this new question.

Thanks in advance.