# Angular5 doesn't recognize jQuery type definitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular5

## Edit:

I'm not using the `angular-cli` since I have this open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8333

So any reference to the `.angular-cli.json` configuration is a bust for me.

---

## Original post:

I've added the `jquery` plugin and yet I get a compilation error when I try to import `$` in my component.

What I did:

- step1:
  `npm install --save jquery` and `npm install -D @types/jquery`
- step2: `import { $ } from 'jquery';` in my component

And typescript gives me this error:

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/components/customer/customer.component.ts:2:10 
    TS2305: Module ''jquery'' has no exported member '$'.`

Project specs:

- asp.net core 2.0
- angular5

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    // other dependencies
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    // other dependencies
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.17",
}
```

---

## Edit:

## <del>Solution:</del>

<del>Having the import like `import * as $ from 'jquery';` works, as in @Nasruddin answer, and includes `jQuery`.</del>

There still remains an <del>visual issue with Visual Studio</del> issue, which gives me this error `Value of type JQueryStatic<TElement extends Node> is not callable.` with TS then interprets and gives this error:

`TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

#### I had to `un-accept` the answer since this doesn't work

<del>For any other that get this error, it's just a visual one, and everything works.</del>

Comment: you mean to write `import  $  from 'jquery';`

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4

Comment: @anshuVersatile Typescript won't allow that: `TS Module 'jquery' has no default export`.

Comment: @Muthu thanks, already checked that question, and tried everything there. Also, importing `jquery` bluntly via the cdn link in my main page is not the option I like, that's why I installed the node modules.

Comment: If you are using CLI please add jquery relative path in .angular-cli.json

Comment: @Nasruddin No, I'm not using the `CLI`, since with the `CLI` I'm faced with this open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8333
So, I'm unable to use the `.angular-cli.json` configuration.
I intentionally omitted the inclusion of the `.angular-cli.json` file, since I don't use it. I'll edit my question.