# Can't Import jQuery into Angular5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I can't import jQuery into Angular5.
I already have done the following:

Installed jQuery via npm:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Placed the path of the "jquery.min.js" into the ".angular.cli.json" :

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  ],
```

Also installed the @types of jQuery:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

And also added (unnecessary, I know) the var's in the "main.ts":

```
declare var jQuery : any;
declare var $ : any;
```

But I still cant use it .. or maybe I use it in the wrong place... momentarily trying to type JS ind the "app.component.ts"

Hope you can help me, thank you for your answers!

Comment: try this `import * as $ from ‘jquery’;`

Comment: Why are you trying to use jQuery in your Angular app? You shouldn't ever have a reason to.

Comment: I can do all buttons, forms, css-classChanges and so on without jQuery in Angular?

Comment: Yes, you can. There shouldn't really ever be a reason to use jQuery in your Angular code. There MIGHT be some special case somewhere, but I can't think of a reason you would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your installation and was successfully able to get jQuery working.  Here's what I added to get the project working.

In **app.component.ts** try adding the following:

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

After that, you should be able to use anything regarding jQuery.

I would look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4) in SO if you have any other quarrels with it.  Best of luck!

Comment: I got it too! You have to declare the var's in every component. I wonder why, but now it works! Thank you!