# jquery doens't work in angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to use jquery in angular 5, specifically I'm trying to use this library:

https://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/eJZQej

These are the steps:

-->I create a new app

```
ng new myApp
```

-->navigate to the new angular app

```
cd myApp
```

-->install dependencies:

```
npm i @angular-devkit/core
```

-->cd src

-->cd app

-->mkdir components

-->cd components

-->I create a component

```
ng g component myComponent1
```

-->in the package.json, in the dependencies section, add 1.11.3
[image]

-->in the index.html add th reference to jquery and the librery:
[image]

-->this is the my-component1 component html:

```html
<div class="page-container">

  <h1>
     jquery-resizable - A simple splitter panel
  </h1>
  <hr />

  <p>
      Simple example that demonstrates how to create slidable two-pane layouts <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox">using FlexBox</a> and the resizable plug-in.
      Note that Flexbox is not required, but used here to keep the layout simple.
  </p>

  <label>Horizontal Splitter Panes:</label>

  <div class="panel-container">

      <div class="panel-left">
          left panel
      </div>

      <div class="splitter">
      </div>

      <div class="panel-right">
          right panel
      </div>
  </div>

  <label>Vertical Splitter Panes:</label>
  <div class="panel-container-vertical">

      <div class="panel-top">
          top panel
      </div>

      <div class="splitter-horizontal">
      </div>

      <div id="panel-bottom">
          bottom panel
      </div>
  </div>



  <hr />

  <p>
      This example creates two resizables for the horizontal and vertical splitter panes:
  </p>

</div>
```

-->this is the my-component1.component.css

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}


/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}


/* vertical panel */

.panel-container-vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-top {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter-horizontal {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/hsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

.panel-bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

pre {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

-->this is the my-component1.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component1',
  templateUrl: './my-component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component1.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(".panel-left").resizable({
      handleSelector: ".splitter",
      resizeHeight: false
    });

    $(".panel-top").animate({height:'72px'}, 500);
  }

}
```

```html
<app-my-component1>loading...</app-my-component1>
```

-->this is the app.component.html

```html
<app-my-component1>loading...</app-my-component1>
```

-->This is the app.module.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

the jquery animation does not work in angular, can someone correct my steps and / or my code

Thanks so much!

Comment: The problem seems rather moot as technically you shouldn't use jQuery and Angular together anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use jQuery in Angular. While it is possible (how to do it you can see here [How to use jQuery Plugin with Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4)), it is discouraged.

Angular holds an own representation of the DOM in its memory and doesn't use query-selectors like jQuery. Instead all the DOM-manipulation is done by Renderer2 (and Angular-directives like *ngFor and *ngIf accessing that Renderer2 in the background/framework-code). If you manipulate DOM with jQuery yourself you will sooner or later run into synchronization problems and have things wrongly appearing or not disappearing at the right time from your screen, errors and simply not being able to test the application correctly (Jasmine requires you to know when elements have been rendered) or being able to use Angular Universal.

Comment: I think this would suite better as a comment. 
Don't get me wrong your explanation on why not to use it is great