# Error while implementing ng2-toasty in Angular2

Tags: angular, toast

I am trying to implement ng2-toasty but the toast notification does not appear at all.

Here's what I have done so far:

1) npm install ng2-toasty --save

2) Added ng2-toasty and it's boostrap file in webpack.config.vendor.js:

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'ng-toasty',
    'ng-toasty/bundles/style-bootstrap.css',
    'jquery',
];
```

3) I also added the following reference in app.module.shared.ts:

```
imports: [    
        ToastyModule.forRoot(),
```

4) Added the tags in app.component.html:

```
<ng2-toasty [position]="'top-right'" > </ng2-toasty>
```

5) Now, when I searched online, I found that I need to run this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

When I ran it, I got the following error:

> ERROR in dll vendor
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-toasty' in 'C:\MyProject'
>        @ dll vendor
>
> ERROR in dll vendor
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-toasty/bundles/style-bootstrap.css' in 'C:\MyProject'
>        @ dll vendor

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using webpack.config.vendor.js directly? NPM's package.json should be sufficient to manage all your app's dependencies.

And stop using jquery with angular. I listed the reasons in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064799/jquery-doenst-work-in-angular-5/50064955#50064955

Comment: why do you even use a toast component that has not been maintained for over a year? angular-material also has a snackbar-component or you could easily write an own yourself.

Comment: I am very new to Angular and have just started following online tutorial on Udemy. So, I am pretty much doing what the instructor does. I will look into the snack-bar component.