# External jQuery files not working on angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular

I have this html code on the app.component.html:

```
<!--================Testimonials Area =================-->
<section class="testimonials_area p_100">
<div class="container">
    <div class="testimonials_slider owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="media">
                <img class="d-flex rounded-circle" src="assets/img/testimonials-1.png" alt="">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <img src="assets/img/dotted-icon.png" alt="">
                    <p>I wanted to mention that these days, when the opposite of good customer and tech support tends to be the norm, it’s always great having a team like you guys at Fancy! So, be sure that I’ll always spread the word about how good your product is and the extraordinary level of support that you provide any time there is any need for it.</p>
                    <h4><a href="#">Aigars Silkalns</a> - CEO DeerCreative</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="media">
                <img class="d-flex rounded-circle" src="assets/img/testimonials-1.png" alt="">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <img src="assets/img/dotted-icon.png" alt="">
                    <p>I wanted to mention that these days, when the opposite of good customer and tech support tends to be the norm, it’s always great having a team like you guys at Fancy! So, be sure that I’ll always spread the word about how good your product is and the extraordinary level of support that you provide any time there is any need for it.</p>
                    <h4><a href="#">Aigars Silkalns</a> - CEO DeerCreative</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="media">
                <img class="d-flex rounded-circle" src="assets/img/testimonials-1.png" alt="">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <img src="assets/img/dotted-icon.png" alt="">
                    <p>I wanted to mention that these days, when the opposite of good customer and tech support tends to be the norm, it’s always great having a team like you guys at Fancy! So, be sure that I’ll always spread the word about how good your product is and the extraordinary level of support that you provide any time there is any need for it.</p>
                    <h4><a href="#">Aigars Silkalns</a> - CEO DeerCreative</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which requires jQuery files that I've added in my assets folder.

jQuery is installed and working fine in my angular project there's no errors in the console and I've added the paths in angular-cli.json but the jQuery code in the files is not called so nothing is working and I get a blank section.

The template is working fine outside angular so the jQuery code is correct.

Any help?

Comment: Do not use jquery with angular. I explained the reasons for it in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064799/jquery-doenst-work-in-angular-5/50064955#50064955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use jQuery plugin on angular. Few step is required.

1. Import jQuery first
2. import your plugin (here OwlCaroussel)
3. Prepare your component like this.

**my.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

// To avoid compile error, let declare jQuery has new usable variable without override original content
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('sliderContent') sliderElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     // your plugin have to be init after the view are init. That means when Angular have finish to add html on DOM.
      // Best approch is to use ViewChild to consume HTMLElement in Angular.
      $(this.sliderElement.nativeElement).owlCarousel();
      // Uncomment this line if you want to let jQuery target himself your element.
      // $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
  }
}
```

on your html, just modify :

```
<div class="testimonials_slider owl-carousel">
```

by

```
<div class="testimonials_slider owl-carousel" #sliderContent>
```

No we have to notice few things on your component.

`declare var $:any;` *make available jQuery on your component*
`ngAfterViewInit()` *we want to init carousel when html is really available.
`$(this.sliderElement.nativeElement).owlCarousel();` *we use ViewChild to improve HTMLElement access and reduce risk of side effect.*

[Online Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-caroussel-angular?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I did as you said, the section is no more empty but it is supposed to show each div at a time not the 3 of them at the same time

Comment: In fact I need to use the function in my custom owl.carousel.min.js not the default one owlCarousel(). How can I do that?

Comment: about your first question, i guess is just something to configure. About your second question, you can replace dependency by your own and `$(this.sliderElement.nativeElement).owlCarousel();`by your own code

Comment: My problem is that the component won't read the js code in the file, I've put it in the right path but it doesn't seem to read it

Comment: please update your question with more detail about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your console. It works for me.

```
npm install -D @types/jquery
```