# Jquery function angular2/5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

I want to use jquery library in my angular5 project

problem: want to enable pagination

installed **jquery using npm**

library: http://pagination.js.org/

however i have added **jquery** and **pagnation** js to my project

**angular-cli.json**

```
  "scripts": [
   "../src/assets/script/custom.js",  //a custom script
    "../src/assets/script/paginathing.js" //the pagination script
  ],
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare var customs:any;
declare var paginathing:any;
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as customs from 'customs';
import * as paginate from 'paginathing';
import * as $ from 'jquery'
// declare var paginathing:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './appeal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appeal.component.css']
})
export class AppealComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  p: number = 1;
  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit() {


    $('.table tbody').paginathing({ //paginathing
      perPage: 4,
    })

  }



}
```

**error**

```
$(...).paginathing is not a function
at AppealComponent.ngOnInit
```

Comment: Use an Angular pagination library. Jquery doesn't go well with Angular anyways.

Comment: @Carsten have googled a lot but no luck in pagination for angular5

Comment: now idea what you googled, but here, an angular material paginator is a good start. https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Comment: Your issue solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create the pagination using the power of Angular and NOT by importing jQuery. Really bad idea to do that..  [continue reading @Phil explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087858/4852044)

check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pagination?embed=1&file=app/pagination/pagination.component.ts)