# Karma/Jasmine Test Failed due to JQuery Operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, webpack, karma-runner

A lengthy search of the google has not yielded anything useful. The test is failing with the following error:

> TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function in config/karma-test-bundle.js (line 436915)

We've got `jquery` loaded in via npm, and I imported the `$` operator into my test file... but I must be missing something. A suggestion to install the `karma-jquery` plug in via npm did not seem to work either. Any clue as to how to resolve this issue?

Edit: Here are some sections of the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
files: [
  {pattern: './config/karma-test-bundle.js', watched: false},
  {pattern: './src/assets/*', watched: false, included: false},
],

proxies: {
  '/assets/': '/base/src/assets/',
},
```

Comment: hi , have u tried karma-jasmine-jquery ? https://github.com/bessdsv/karma-jasmine-jquery

Comment: do you have your karma.conf available to share?

Comment: @FatehMohamed - yes, tried it... no joy.

Comment: @Rikin - is there something in there you would be looking for? It's a long file and I'd rather not make the question too hard to get through for future readers.

Comment: `config.set files: []` if you have it. We use `proxies: { '/assets/': '/base/build/assets/' },` as well to map out file bundle correctly

Comment: @Rikin, Sure. Edited the question.

Comment: I suggest using the excellent ngx-bootstrap tooltip component instead of jQuery. jQuery is a nightmare with Angular; see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087858/4125622

Comment: How is your main/vendor bundle file being included? Also is jquery in dependencies for your project in `package.json`

Comment: @Rikin, yes jquery is in package.json. I don't know how to answer the second question, I'm pretty new to Angular.

Comment: If it's any help, we think this may be a webpack-related issue. Adding that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add `require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');` to your `config/karma-test-bundle.js` file.