# Using javascript file in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I want use this [JQUERY TABLEHEADFIXER](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html) in my project, and i tried:

**index.html**

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/tableHeadFixer.js"></script>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 declare var $: any;
 declare var tableHeadFixer: any;
```

and then i call:

```
$('#dongbocmis_table').tableHeadFixer();
```

but i got this errors

> $(...).tableHeadFixer is not a function

so how i can fix it ?

Comment: In place of `declare var tableHeadFixer: any;`  
try this


`declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;`

for more detail can follow this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4

Comment: What way you using this is not a proper way to work with angular. You should create a directive with tableHeadFixer then apply it on element.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @AshishYadav: i added it, and jquey work well, but i get error on tableHeadFixer

Comment: @jimboR, Please follow this `https://jsfiddle.net/2007ay/u380uLg0/9/` jsfiddle link, the same thing I have done my local its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

In Angular (> v6) right way to import all files to include it into the `.angular-cli.json` file under the `styles` and `scripts` array; like this:

```
        "styles": [
           ...
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "assets/js/tableHeadFixer.js"
        ],
```

So remove all the CDN's and files from Index.html file and import like this.

Secondly, you need to declare jQuery as well

```
declare var $: any;
```

Let me know if any error still show up.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare `$`. Do not declare tableHeadFixer.

`declare const $;`

Comment: i added it, and jquey work well, but i get error on tableHeadFixer

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for breaking it to you but your question reflects what’s wrong in JavaScript community today. You are asking

> How to use JavaScript into Angular?

jQuery and Angular are both JavaScript. The programming paradign they introduce doesn’t change this fact.

TypeScript code you shared will also compile to JavaScript. (Assuming you are transpiling your .TS files before trying to run it in the web browser)

You see your question and code snippets makes my eyes pop out and really makes me cry for help!

Anyways, let me try to help you with code. When you import jQuery it registers a global variable. So in your web browser ‘$’ will be available after your `<script>` tag.

From my understanding you are running this plugin before the DOM table has been added to the web page.

You can check if $ is available by running `console.log($);` or `alert($);`

Then you can check if jQuery plugin is named right by doing `console.log($.fn)` and inspecting the object in the console panel.

The console.log will log output to web browser’s console panel.

One important thing to note is that something else (or multiple jQuery) is overwriting $ then this jQuery plugin will be lost.

Go to browser console and start typing ‘jQuer’ and it will show you if there are multiple instances of jQuery.

You may also try, jQuery() function instead of $() as in `jQuery('#dongbocmis_table').tableHeadFixer();`

I hope this helps.

-Sameer G