# Is neccesary include JQuery in an Angular - semantic project

Tags: jquery, angular, semantic-ui

I am working with Semantic + Angular 6.

After installing semantic I get this from the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>       at semantic.min.js:11

So now, my question is: Do I really need jquery in angular 6?

How can I include it?

Comment: You should avoid using jQuery with angular. However, I'm not sure if tehre are any project for semantic and angular 6. Here is one for angular 4, which does not require jQuery: 
https://github.com/edcarroll/ng2-semantic-ui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery Plugin with Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4)

Comment: The version is different, and the solution depends on the theming library that you use, is not the same replace jquery for bootstrap or replace jquery for semantic. @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Angular and jQuery don't go together - this is the fundamental principal of this library. It provides Angular component versions of the Semantic UI modules, so that you don't need to add jQuery to your app.**

Check this [project](https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/getting-started)