# Getting jQuery errors after install Angular Datatables

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I follow instructions to [install](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic) Angular Datatables

After install all modules and added styles and scripts to `angular-cli.json` I use test data like [this](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic)

But I get two errors:

> ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>
> ERROR Error: NomDatatable element exist.

Module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { UsuariosComponent } from "./usuarios.component";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { DefaultComponent } from "../../default.component";
import { LayoutModule } from "../../../../layouts/layout.module";
import { DataTablesModule } from "angular-datatables";

// This Module's Components
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: DefaultComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: UsuariosComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    LayoutModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DataTablesModule
  ],
  declarations: [UsuariosComponent]
})
export class UsuariosModule {}
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { ModalDismissReasons, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { ScriptLoaderService } from "../../../../../_services/script-loader.service";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";

@Component({
  selector: "app-base-data-json",
  templateUrl: "./usuarios.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})


export class UsuariosComponent {
  constructor(
    private _script: ScriptLoaderService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._script.loadScripts("app-base-data-json", [
      "assets/app/base/usuarios/get-usuarios.js"
    ]);
  }
}
```

Component.html:

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Someone</td>
            <td>Youknow</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Iamout</td>
            <td>Ofinspiration</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Yoda</td>
            <td>Skywalker</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Patrick</td>
            <td>Dupont</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Barack</td>
            <td>Obama</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>François</td>
            <td>Holland</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Michel</td>
            <td>Popo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Chuck</td>
            <td>Norris</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Simon</td>
            <td>Robin</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Louis</td>
            <td>Lin</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Zelda</td>
            <td>Link</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Angular-cli

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
      ],
```

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: In which component are you trying to show table?

Comment: I update my question with component @yer

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery with Angular. if you want to use datatable use libraries without jQuery like PrimeNG, ngBootstrap, and MDB

Comment: Angular documentation recomends jquery? It should work with packages they give with npm @PatricioVargas

Comment: I'm surprised you are telling me Angular documentation suggest tonuse jQuery. Can you send me the link please? Every library that has come out for Angular explicitly advertise that they don't use jQuery

Comment: @Pedro please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4/50087858#50087858 I wrote why you should not use jQuery with Angular. The best alternatives are (in that order) AgGrid, PrimeNG Turbo Table and Material Table. Save yourself the trouble before it's too late

Comment: please create a stackblitz to reflect the error. When I followed the same instructions to install and use datatable it was working fine.