# How Import JS File in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, file, import

how can I import a js file in angular 6. 
I tried to implement a navbar and it contains js functions.
thanks!!!

I Add my js file called nav.js

```
 "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/nav.js"
        ]
```

Comment: Working example to include jquery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4

Answer (score 3):

Angular 6 has a dedicated place to declare js files
within the dedicated arrays of your angular.json,
under

```
 /projects/$(youProjectName)/architect/build/options/scripts[]
```

and

```
 /projects/$(youProjectName)/architect/test/options/scripts[]
```

As an example:

```
npm install fast-levenshtein --save
```

will install a js library under node-modules

The path relative to the project of the js lib file is declared like this:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/fast-levenshtein/levenshtein.js"
]
```

Then declare in your component the variable(s) to use, 
either as described by the npm documentation or by @LuaXD

Comment: what if it's a custom js file. how do i declare the variables

Answer (score 2):

You should include on index.html, e.g:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>A random project</title>
   <base href="/">

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb- 
  libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" 
/>
<script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.core.js"></script>

<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

On this case I included cartodb.js library, then for use cartodb.js on any component, or service I use:

```
declare var cartodb: any;
```

At the beginning of any file (Component, Service, etc).

Note change cartodb by the name of the library you will use, for example for jquery is:

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

You should have something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// Other imports...

declare var cartodb: any;
@Injectable()
export class ARandomService {
}
```

P.s Search if the code you want to use doesn't exist in npm.

Comment: instead of using declare var, can't we import the files?

Comment: declare var cartodb: any;
declare var jquery:any;
declare var jquery-ui:any;

I can import multiple libraries like that in my TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

first, you should install your library with npm. then the library is being added to your node_modules folder, in your project.

now:

if you want to import js files into the angular project, first you should check the version of angular, if you are using version 2 and 4 , you should write like this :

```
      "scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

and if you are using version upper than 4, like 5,6 or 7 you should write like this :

```
      "scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

in this example i import jquery into the angular project. i hope, it works

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some workaround if you can grasp the functions within the script.
So You either put them in your component.ts code as functions ,or if you can't/don't want to , you will just have to export/import them . for example

myscript.js

```
  function a(){ ...}
    function b(){...}


    module.exports.a=a
    module.exports.b=b
```

mycomponent.component.ts

```
..
import a from './path/../myscript.js';
import b from './path/../myscript.js';

..
constructor(){
...
a.a()
b.b()
...
}
```

ps:many times you will find function anonymous so you just have to rename them ,
for example

myscript.js

function(){..}();

will be

myscript.js

```
function myCustomName(){..};
module.exports.customName=myCustomName
```