# Include Js files into Angular 6 project

Tags: angular

I downloaded a ready to use template that contains HTML, CSS and Js files for an Angular project. 
The HTML file need tthe Js files to work correctly. 
How can i add the Js files?

PS: i have already added the script in index.html and the path  in angulas.json but it didn't work

Comment: What kind of template?  What do these files do?

Comment: Side menu template

Answer (score 1):

ther are plenty answers on this subject, for example:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649194/how-import-js-file-in-angular-6)

say you have library abc.js, add the following code to the angular components:

```
declare var abc: any;
```