# Owl Carousel 2 is not working with Angular 5

Tags: angular5, owl-carousel-2

I need to use OwlCarousel2 with Angular5 and I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel but its showing error please see the image below for reference. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Let's try my answer and let me know if still errors

Comment: did you tried.My answer. What happened?

Comment: No @KarnanMuthukumar its still showing same error. I have followed all steps but still unable to understand what's wrong.

Comment: still same error? ok please wait few min i will make some OwlCarousel2 for you.

Comment: Give that OwlCarousel2  link what you have used?

Comment: I'm need to use this one https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html

Comment: Any luck @KarnanMuthukumar?

Comment: Iam also face some issue run time

Comment: Ok but thank you very much for your time. Really appreciated :)

Comment: did ypu solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, @user9964622 this issue has been solved.

Comment: @HiraMajid how did you solve it? can you share the source codes? I want to use owlcarousel in my angular 6 app

Comment: @user9964622 I tried to add this code in Angular6 but it was not working. I can share my code with you if you want.

Comment: so in which angular does it work? am using  6 though :(

Comment: can you share the source code? I will try to and see what I can do

Comment: It's working on Angular 5.

Comment: @HiraMajid can you please share your code?

Comment: npm install script-loader

npm install ngx-owl-carousel --save

Run above commands

Comment: I have installed the ngx-owl-carousel and I have  followed their instructions  here is my thread I have opened, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930994/ngx-owl-carousel-is-not-working-in-angular-6,

Comment: I want to see the working demo, so if you can provide  your source code in github?

Comment: @user9964622 I have posted my answer below please check if this can help you.

Comment: mhh bro  that is not problem, can you provide your working source codes?

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot thats not a owl carousel problem. It occured not included jquery in your app component file.

So install using following command

```
npm install jquery — save
```

Add jquery file in .angular.json file

```
“scripts”: [ “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js” ]
```

Then import it as follows in app.component.ts file.

```
import * as $ from ‘jquery’;
```

Then now you can use errors gone.

Note:-

If you want to use bootstrap in your application or if you already have in your project, make sure to include jQuery before including the bootstrap javascript file as follows. Since bootstrap’s javascript file requires jQuery.

```
“scripts”: [ “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js”,
“../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js”]
```

Reference link:-
https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176&hl=en-IN

https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4&hl=en-IN

Here is the two link give some idea to import jquery in your app.

Please try once and let me know.

I hope it's solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands and check below files for Owl carousel slider.

```
npm install script-loader
npm install ngx-owl-carousel --save

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zi1zTX4rks-es1lZsE0bcfmnoYtjygIp
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qarsnGqYL_P6ryYNh3mLm4ClUqkchxhv
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1or-6D-PGzW-NCFRiMykG4YnF2Mto33kc
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QcYILCD_eByrF8r70-vERNgeAImkQT6i
```

Comment: I am using angular cli so I dont need script loader i just added files though angular.json , if you have the code which is working in angular 5  , can you provide   via git hub ot stackblitz ?