# How to implement bootstrap scrollspy in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

My code runs with Angular 6 and and Bootstrap 4. In the end I want to have bootstrap's scrollspy component running in this setup. Bootstrap requires jQuery and I do not know how to get it working.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div class="header-nav">
    <nav id="home-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_header"
        aria-controls="navbar_header" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_header">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#our_mission">Our Mission</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#our_clients">our clients</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#features">features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#faqs">Faqs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="main-content">
  <section id="home">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="../../../assets/landing-page/images/slider-1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../../../assets/landing-page/images/slider-1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../../../assets/landing-page/images/slider-1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="our_mission">
    <p>AAAAAAAAAA</p>
  </section>
  <section id="our_clients"></section>
  <section id="features"></section>
  <section id="pricing"></section>
  <section id="faqs"></section>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
ngOnInit() {
  $('.main-content').scrollspy({ target: '#home-nav' });
}
```

Comment: Do have solved it already?

Comment: no it's still pending. any help will appreciate

Comment: Today I won't tackle it any more, but tomorrow I will need that function also. The point is, that you'll need to implement jQuery into your Angular Code. You will need to declare the dollar sign `$` corresponding to jQuery's syntax, define it inside your webpack or ts config. I will hand in something tomorrow, ok?

Comment: Have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4

Comment: Especially that answer and the one**s** below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996506/4892206

Comment: i did tried that before but no luck i will wait for your answer once again thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @yaseen-ahmed I've still did not reach out for testing this. My project is not making such progress. But I did not forget it. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it would be better if you built a working example on sites like codepen or stackblitz. that will make us easy to see the problem.

```
<header>
  <div class="header-nav" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
    <nav id="home-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_header"
        aria-controls="navbar_header" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_header">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#our_mission">Our Mission</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#our_clients">our clients</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#features">features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#faqs">Faqs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="main-content">
  <section id="home">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="../../../assets/landing-page/images/slider-1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../../../assets/landing-page/images/slider-1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="../../../assets/landing-page/images/slider-1.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="our_mission">
    <p>AAAAAAAAAA</p>
  </section>
  <section id="our_clients"></section>
  <section id="features"></section>
  <section id="pricing"></section>
  <section id="faqs"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working in angular 6 i did tried this before. i need angular base solution any help will appreciate.

Comment: @YaseenAhmad , It would be better if you provide us a working code on fsfiddle or stackblitz.

Comment: here is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbgx8m it's working fine there i use lazzy load method not sure why it's not working in my code.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/thisissoon/angular-scrollspy or ngx-scrollspy?

Comment: i don't want to use this because i'm working on 2 layer project one layer is scrollspy and the another one is simple.

Comment: Consider using the comment function instead of posting an answer. That is confusing.