# Jquery not loading with Angular typescript

Tags: angular

I want to add jquery in my angular project,but it is not working.
I have try multiple solution but it is not working.

**Error**

```
ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at SignInComponent.push../src/app/users/sign-in/sign-in.component.ts.SignInComponent.ngOnInit (sign-in.component.ts:28)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22099)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SignInComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
```

**What i tried**

```
- npm install jquery — save
```

and then

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

**My Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Renderer2, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-master',
  templateUrl: './master.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./master.component.css']
})

export class MasterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('call');
    console.log($(document));
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate this isn’t an answer, but I think you’re best avoiding trying to use jQuery with Angular if possible. I tried it once and just got a mess. Do you need it for something specific? If so I’d really recommend trying to find an Angular solution.

Comment: This one should work just fine =)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996506/5811368

Comment: @Muhammad u did `ng serve` after adding it to to `scripts:[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be your script path in the angular.json file, change it this way(remove one dot):

```
"scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use @types/jquery

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery

```
npm i @types/jquery
```

Comment: this is not the exact answer to the question but has solved the issue i am facing, I have jquery install but not types installed, after installing types able to call jquery plugin functions