# Bootstrap 4 'data-toggle' preventing AngualrJS model updating

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I've seen this mentioned as an issue for Bootstrap 3 with no official fix, but not mentioned for Bootstrap 4.

[Plunker Demo of issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/v0JKuOLxy3rbIeQMd4bQ?p=preview)

The data-toggle is used on a radio input, when data-toggle is on the input the AJS model isn't updated, but without it it is. 
Plus the added issue of if I don't use data-toggle then no toggle affect is applied to the selected radio option.

```
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--ISSUE SCRIPT - data-toggle -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

  <body ng-controller="testController">
        <form>
           <!-- YES/NO -->
                <div class="form-group required">
                  <label class="input-label">Do you have any debt?</label>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="HasDebt" autocomplete="off"
                          ng-value="true"
                          ng-model="User.HasDebt"> Yes
                      </label>
                      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="HasDebt" autocomplete="off"
                          ng-value="false"
                          ng-model="User.HasDebt"> No
                      </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                Value: {{User.HasDebt}}
        </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43934727/712526), since Bootstrap relies on jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS version that you are using is not compatible with jQuery it seems. Please replace it with the latest version. Below is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS -->

    <!--ISSUE SCRIPT - data-toggle -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

  <body ng-controller="testController">
        <form>
           <!-- YES/NO -->
                <div class="form-group required">
                  <label class="input-label">Do you have any debt?</label>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="HasDebt" autocomplete="off"
                          ng-value="true"
                          ng-model="User.HasDebt"> Yes
                      </label>
                      <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="HasDebt" autocomplete="off"
                          ng-value="false"
                          ng-model="User.HasDebt"> No
                      </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                Value: {{User.HasDebt}}
        </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't help :( Jquery needs to be called before the Bootstrap script for the bootstrap script doesn't work at all, so placing the scripts at the bottom but BS script at the top means the page acts as if the BS script wasn't there at all. And placing the jquery script back at the top means the model isn't updated but BS script works :/

Comment: I copy this code in your plunkr and it works fine for me, I tried to call jquery before bootstrap and it doesn't work that way.

Comment: The bootstrap script isn't running, when you select one of the radio buttons no selected style is applied. Only the general BS4 style is being present compared to : https://plnkr.co/edit/v0JKuOLxy3rbIeQMd4bQ?p=preview a radio select with no indication of which is selected in't much use.

Comment: The angularjs version 1.4.0 which you are using is not compatible with jquery it seems. Please replace it with the latest version, I've updated my code.

Comment: ayyy great, thanks, I stupidly thought I'd gotten the latest version some how.