# Rewrite jQuery function to Angular 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am very new to Angular and currently am struggling with rewriting a jQuery code I use to load my ["classycountdown" script](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Slick-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Plugin-Classy-Countdown/).
This is the jQuery function I want to translate:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var remainingSec = $('.countdown').data('remaining-sec');
  $('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
        theme: "flat-colors-very-wide",
        end: $.now() + remainingSec
    });
    });
```

This is the html where it's used:

```html
<div class="countdown" 
[attr.data-remaining-sec]="toSec.seconds">
</div>
```

and this is part of the component code for the toSec variable:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
....
    toSec = {
        seconds: this.scnds
      }
}
```

The reason why I want to convert it to Angular is because the function doesn't work the first time the page is loaded, which I assume is because the view is not loaded yet and when it goes through this statement: var remainingSec = $('.countdown').data('remaining-sec'); it doesn't find anything on the first load. However, once I hit refresh it would start working. Also, for some reason I haven't had this issue when I was testing it on localhost, it only started showing when I deployed it to the server.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Why not run the script inside onInit of the component instead of $(document).ready?

Comment: I get an error when I do that: ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).ClassyCountdown is not a function at AppComponent.ngOnInit (main.js:175) at callHook (vendor.js:13847) at callHooks (vendor.js:13811) at executeInitAndCheckHooks (vendor.js:13751) at refreshView (vendor.js:20240) at renderComponentOrTemplate (vendor.js:20356) at tickRootContext (vendor.js:21879) at detectChangesInRootView (vendor.js:21913)....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the angular component lifecycle hook **OnAfterViewInit** instead of doc ready. Probably don't try to rewrite the thing in angular it'll be a big job with little gain.

```
import $ from "jquery";

export class AppComponent implements OnAfterViewInit {
  constructor() {}
  
  ngOnAfterViewInit() {

    const remainingSec = $('.countdown').data('remaining-sec');
    
    $('.countdown').ClassyCountdown({
       theme: "flat-colors-very-wide",
       end: $.now() + remainingSec
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Downvote for suggesting jQuery in Angular. OP is asking how to rewrite it for Angular.

Comment: if the plugin requires jQuery then why wouldn't you just either wedge it or find an angular alternative?

Comment: Because "npm install jquery" gets you sacked. Them is the rules!

Comment: respect your purism but your answer only implements a basic timer not any of the UI or features the plugin in question provides.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting this error when I run your code:
ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).ClassyCountdown is not a function
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (main.js:175)
    at callHook (vendor.js:13847)
    at callHooks (vendor.js:13811)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (vendor.js:13751)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:20240)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (vendor.js:20356)
    at tickRootContext (vendor.js:21879)
    at detectChangesInRootView (vendor.js:21913).....
.........

Comment: ah so now the function is called but it looks like the ClassyCountdown script hasn't loaded yet, where in your project did you add it? I think maybe it'll need to go in the index.html

Comment: try this thread for ways to include jquery and jquery plugins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4

Comment: I tried the jQuery workaround, and I am not getting the error anymore, however this doesn't solve my problem and I am back to square 1 as the view seems to not be loaded yet when I make the call in onInit():
$(".countdown").data("remaining-sec")
>> undefined

Comment: You know what.. I just tried using it in OnAfterViewInit and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: cool, made the edits for prosperity glad it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Create an observable that emits the countdown you want

```
timer$ = timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
  take(10), 
  map(val => 10 - val)
);
```

timer(1000, 1000) emits ascending numbers every second, take(10) is how many you want to emit and map makes it count down from ten. You should be able to play with that to get the values you want to count down from.

and in the template use the async pipe to display the emitted values.

```
{{ timer$ | async }} left to go
```

Here is a pure JS demo of the timer observable.

```js
const { timer } = rxjs;
const { take, map } = rxjs.operators;

timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
  take(10),
  map(val => 10 - val)
).subscribe(time => { console.log(time); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know how this helps me in translating the jQuery code to Angular.. In addition to that, I don't need a new countdown script, I already have a script I am using. Thanks for your comment though.